# Why can't I take screenshots in my Steam games?

Tags: steam, ubuntu, wine

I installed Steam through Winetricks on Ubuntu, and I can't take any screenshots.  I can't get the Steam overlay to come up either.

I've checked that the overlay is enabled in multiple places.

What's wrong?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Steam is now available in beta on Linux.
http://store.steampowered.com/about/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a bug with Steam under Wine, where the overlay causes some games to crash.

To prevent this, Winetricks installs Steam with one library override:

```
gameoverlayrenderer.dll (disabled)
```

Which, naturally, disables the Steam overlay, and the in-game functions it provides, such as screenshotting.

To change this, open `winecfg` in the proper wineprefix (for me, Winetricks made it `~/.local/share/wineprefixes/steam`, so I used `WINEPREFIX=~/.local/share/wineprefixes/steam winecfg`), and change it.  I set it to Native then Builtin, and so far it seems to be working fine...

Unless you *must* have the overlay, I would disable this again when you're done taking your screenshots to prevent it from messing anything else up.